# symfony2 application and capifony error

Tags: deployment, symfony, capifony

I have been trying to deploy a symfony2 app via capifony but I keep getting an error at assets:install step. Here is the output when I run cap deploy:

```
--> Updating code base with checkout strategy
--> Creating cache directory...........................✔
--> Creating symlinks for shared directories...........✔
--> Creating symlinks for shared files.................✔
--> Normalizing asset timestamps.......................✔
--> Reinstalling vendors...............................✔
--> Building bootstrap file............................✔
--> Installing bundle's assets.........................✘
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
failed: "sh -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\'' sh -c '\\''cd /var/www/example.com/releases/20120919025653 && php app/console assets:install web  --env=prod'\\'''" on stage.example.com
```

It fails while installing bundle's assets. Anyone run into this situation? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Add following line to your app/config/deploy.rb to increase the verbosity:

```
logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
```

You should be able to see what went wrong.

I can see you're using sudo. Is it installed? Did you give rights to use it to the user you deploy with?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's months late, but this just caught me out on a new server setup.

The reason was that the `date.timezone` setting was not set in `php.ini` and this threw an `ErrorException` when running `php app/console assets:install web --env=prod`